# Access to Apache Subdomains externally

Tags: server, apache2, dns

I just recently configured a localhost subdomain on my Apache web server.

domain: `hjm.im` 
subdomain: `blog.hjm.im`

It is working correctly from on my server (which makes sense), but how can I get access to it from the outside. If you type `blog.hjm.im` into your browser nothing gets returned.

Do I need to create a DNS record? Or is there some setting inside of Apache that does this for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have a CNAME record in DNS that points to your FQDN. You should also have your subdomain parameters listed in `/etc/apache2/sites-available/blog.hjm.im.conf`  The request  for the subdomain will be forwarded to your server and Apache will resolve the request for the subdomain. This is exactly how I have my server configured with seven subdomains.

The values you had entered for the virtual server instance you had in your previous (removed) post looked fine for the virtual server instance, other than they were lumped into the same file with your root domain.

Comment: The configuration files seem to be working because I can see the subdomain on the local host. I have never actually created a DNS record, how do I do that  ?

Comment: Localhost lookups will almost always work unless something is really wrong with the Apache configuration. How to add the DNS record will depend on who is managing your DNS service. If you are using an external DNS service, check with them on how to add a CNAME record. If you are managing your DNS internally, add the record to `/etc/bind/named.conf.local`:  `blog.hjm.im  CNAME IN hjm.im` (I'm assuming that you do have a registered domain and that you're masking the real domain name in your posts?)

Comment: The hosting service I am using is called DigitalOcean and I had previously set up A records for `blog.hjm.im` and `resume.hjm.im` Any additional thoughts ? I guess Ill need to contact them.

Comment: I'm getting resolution to both your root domain and your blog subdomain at the moment. The root domain shows an empty page but does have your name as the page title. For the subdomain, I get a variant of the default Apache page with "SubDomain works!!!" as the header. Looks like you've made progress!

Comment: Yeah I actually had the DNS records incorrect. I was specifying the full name `blog.hjm.im` instead of just blog in the DNS A record, so it wasn't routing to my domain. Thanks for all of your help.